# Is it possible to use the CPack DEB generator on Windows to create deb packages?

Tags: windows, cmake, cross-compiling, deb, cpack

[The documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html) for CPack DEB generator says it's Unix only. At the same time there's "Building Debian packages on Windows" paragraph.

I use Windows on my development machine and cross-compile for ARM Debian Linux. The project uses CMake. I'd like to confirm whether it's possible to create deb package in Windows or I should investigate other means.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the crosscompiler running on windows directly? I've successfully built & packaged programs using WSL and depending how you're building the project, you may already be using a virtual linux environment and in that case there's probably little to no work to be done to make the package generator work...

Comment: @fabian yes, I'm not using WSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried it myself and it worked out of the box, no Windows specifics required. Used https://decovar.dev/blog/2021/09/23/cmake-cpack-package-deb-apt/ as a reference.